# unittest for try except if else python

Tags: python, mysql, unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing

During my test coverage, some lines are missed and I try to figure out the solution but couldn't successful.

```
try: 
    conn.database = DB_NAME
```

below lines are missed in test coverage

```
except mysql.connector.Error as err: 
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: 
        create_database(cursor, DB_NAME) 
        conn.database = DB_NAME 
    else: 
        print(err) 
        exit(1) 
 cursor.close() 
 cnx.close()
```

Can someone help me to write an assertion test for testing this kind code?. This code is verify database name whether it is present or not.

Comment: Do you have only `conn.database = DB_NAME` line under the `try` body?

Comment: @alecxe yes I have only conn.database = DB_NAME line under try body and I globally declare DB_NAME .

Comment: Thanks, could you provide a "successful" test when you have the `DB_NAME` declared?

Comment: @alecxe I didn't understand you . I will try to explain. I am creating a TABLE in database dynamically with python script, then by calling that function in test file, it says nothing except for showing missing lines. I will edit my question to add that whole function. maybe you gave me a tip then. thanx.

Comment: Can you not just put inside you try statment: 'raise mysql.connector.Error'? That would then force your code to take that path

Comment: @BretD you mean inside try statement I put raise mysql.connector.Erroe?

Comment: @royshah Firstly, you are only doing an assignment in a try block, which I can't imagine how the assignment would raise that error. So I think your try except statement there does nothing. That said, if you raised that error in the try block as I mentioned, that would cause your code to take that path, since it is set to catch that exception

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your unit test - it doesn't look like you are testing `royRead` at all. Or is there more code you haven't shown?

Comment: @AndrewGuy testing = royRead(param1, param2) , by adding this line it shows that only a certain part is missed in coverage test.

Comment: @roysah, I think you are missing the point of a unit test. You want to run `royRead`, and then test that it does what you require of it. There's nothing in your code that actually tests `royRead`. You have 0% coverage of `royRead` in practice, even if your unit test framework tells you that you have coverage. Have good read through this - https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/09/improve-your-python-understanding-unit-testing/